# Eclipse Preference Pages

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, preferences, rcp

I have created a preference page in eclipse the preference page has two fields

1. server url
2. store location

If the user open this preferences dialog, change the value of url and apply it the product is restarted and after restart when I check the value in the url field it is changed as expected. When I change the values of both url and directory only one of them is updated depends on which one is changed later. 
Here is my init method which initialize the preferences

```
public class DataStorePreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

public static final String SERVER_URL = "prefs_server_url";
public static final String WORKSPACE_DIR = "prefs_workspace_dir";
public static final String KEEP_LOCKS = "prefs_keep_locks";
//public static final String RELEASE = "prefs_release";
public DataStorePreferencePage() {
    super(GRID);
}


@Override
public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
    setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
    getPreferenceStore().addPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            String property = event.getProperty();
            System.setProperty("datastoreserver_url", property);
            if (property.equals(DataStorePreferencePage.WORKSPACE_DIR) ||
                    property.equals(DataStorePreferencePage.SERVER_URL)) {

                if(MessageDialog.openConfirm(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), "Information", "New settings will be applied after a restart.\nRestart now?"))
                    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart();

            }
        }
    });                     
}

@Override
protected void createFieldEditors() {
    StringFieldEditor urlEditor = new StringFieldEditor(SERVER_URL, "DataStore Server URL", getFieldEditorParent());
    StringFieldEditor workspaceDirEditor = new DirectoryFieldEditor(WORKSPACE_DIR, "Workspace directory:", getFieldEditorParent());
    BooleanFieldEditor keepLocksEditor = new BooleanFieldEditor(KEEP_LOCKS, "Keep locks (default setting):", getFieldEditorParent());
    //BooleanFieldEditor releaseEditor = new BooleanFieldEditor(RELEASE, "Release (default setting):", getFieldEditorParent());

    addField(workspaceDirEditor);
    addField(urlEditor);
    addField(keepLocksEditor);
    //addField(releaseEditor);
}

@Override
public boolean performOk() {

    return super.performOk();

}


}
```

Question:

Where is the new value stored? From where eclipse get this changed value in any .ini file?

How can I change both the properties at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: You need to wait until `performOK` or `performApply` is called before trying to do the restart.

Comment: When I do performOk or performApply where are these new values stored?

Comment: I can't tell as you haven't shown us enough code

Comment: Is the restart for testing purposes or part of your application?  If part of the application, why?

Comment: I just removed the restart its not required the changes take effect even without restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait until `performOk` or `performApply` is called before checking for restart.

The preference values are stored in the preference store. You can get them with:

```
IPreferenceStore store = getPreferenceStore();

String dir = store.getString(WORKSPACE_DIR);

String url = store.getString(SERVER_URL);
```

Comment: Is this preference store any ini file or its just created in memory or what ?

Comment: How can I ensure that performOk is called before I check for restart? Do I need to call performOk before checking for restart ?

Comment: Eclipse will call performOk if the user clicks 'OK' (and `performApply' if they click 'Apply'). If they click Cancel the new values are discarded and you should not do a restart.

Comment: when I change both the values i-e url and dir, performOk() is called two times once for each field. After each performOk() call propertyChange Listener is called. How can I ensure that performOk() is called for all the values that are changed?

Comment: Eclipse should only call performOk once when the OK button is clicked, I have never seen it behave any other way.

Comment: The performApply also call performOk() internally. How can I restart my product on clicking upon Ok button instead of clicking on Apply

Comment: You can override performApply if you want, but you should really take the same action for Apply as OK

Comment: Thanks for your tips , after overriding performApply I solved my problem Thanks

Comment: Eclipse stores its all preferences in files. Check the following folder in your workspace folder.
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/